# Mobile app to measure rooms and generate floor plans

Tags: image-processing, mobile

Is there a mobile application than can measure a room and generate a floor plan?

I'm imaging a workflow like taking a series of photographs, and have the app do clever image processing to determine the floor plan including measurements.

I realize this is difficult technically, but it would be so useful, I wondered if any apps are available.

Comment: For which mobile OS? In case of Android, check [my list here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/various_roomplanning) and make your choice ;) Only handicap: no such app comes without any trackers. Up to 12 per app in this case… But there's one with just one tracker…

Answer (score 1):

Not a mobile App, as I suspect that the processing requirements may well be beyond many mobiles.

I would suggest taking a series of photographs or a video of each room, transferring to a larger machine to run a Photogrammetric process on it.

One such workflow is [Alice Vision](https://github.com/alicevision/AliceVision) *there are several others* at the end of such a workflow you will have a 3D mesh model that you and either use for a 3-D model or a 2-D floor plan using tools such as [Blender 3-D](https://www.blender.org/) or [Sketchup](https://www.sketchup.com/).